# clarification about the definition of inverse linear mapping

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Definition: Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces, and let $T:V \rightarrow W$ be linear. A function $U:W \rightarrow V$ is said to be an inverse of $T$ if $TU=I_W$ and $UT=I_V$

Does that mean when we do the matrix multiplication of whatever the function is for $T$ and whatever function is for $U$, we get an identity matrix that has the basis of $W$?

Comment: It means: given a basis $\beta$ for $V$ and a basis $\gamma$ for $W$, if $A$ is the matrix for $T$ relative to $\beta$ and $\gamma$ and $B$ is the matrix for $U$ relative to $\gamma$ and $\beta$, then $AB$ and $BA$ are both the identity matrices (of the appropriate size; which turns out to be the same size for finite dimensions)

Comment: In general there are no matrices associated with LT's. I suppose you are assuming that $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Do you mean $[A]^{\beta}_{\gamma}$* $[B]^{\gamma}_{\beta}$?

Comment: No, I mean $A=[T]_{\beta}^{\gamma}$, $B=[U]_{\gamma}^{\beta}$, so that $AB = [TU]_{\gamma}^{\gamma}$ and $BA=[UT]_{\beta}^{\beta}$.